# Sorting by position in MySQL, multiple products assigned to one position

Tags: mysql, sorting

I'm using an ecommerce system and I'm trying to modify how products are sorted.

My question is, how does mysql deal with sorting when two items have the same value?

e.g.

Products are sorted by a position that is assigned to them (so position 1 would display at the top).

However, if I have 3 products assigned to position 1 and 2 products assigned to position 2, how are the 3 products assigned to position 1 sorted by default? Would this be specific to the ecommerce system or is there a mysql default, such as ID?

I hope this is clear enough, I've not been able to really find any good answers by Googling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify additional fields on which to order by, the earliest ones take precedence but latter ones decide how to break ties.  For example:

```
ORDER BY foo ASC, bar DESC
```

Comment: Perfect, i'll give this a go! Who knew it would be so simple eh?

Answer (score 0):

The result is random since no other "default" order will be applied. If you need to sort by more than one column you can do it like this

```
order by position, id, date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give multiple column names (say A,B,C) in the `ORDER BY` clause.  When values are equal in A, then B is used to make sorting decisions. If also equal in B, then C is used.  This called a lexicographic ordering.  See any SQL documentationn of the `SELECT` command and `ORDER BY` clause.